# Nativescript: Controlling sideDrawer logically

Tags: javascript, telerik, nativescript

**Hi there people!**

I'm trying to make a side drawer with **Nativescript** and **Javascript** that is shown over the navigation bar.

The package I'm using is [Telerik Ui for Nativescript](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/introduction).

The fact is that even if I can make the drawer shown over the navigation bar when I use the slide gesture, I can't control it from a `tap="function()"` directive.

- This is the official documentation on [action bars that are shown over the navigation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/SideDrawer/getting-started#showing-radsidedrawer-over-the-navigation-baraction-bar)
- This is the official documentation on [logic control of the drawer](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/SideDrawer/programmatic)

This is my code in `main-page.xml` (I use **nativescript-telerik-ui** which is the free version and not **nativescript-telerik-ui-pro**)

```
<dpg:DrawerPage loaded="pageLoaded" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo"  
xmlns:dpg="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/drawerpage"
xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer"
xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
<navigation.actionBar>
  <ActionBar title="Drawer Over Navigation" />
</navigation.actionBar>

<dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer>
<drawer:RadSideDrawer id="drawer">
  <drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
    <StackLayout cssClass="drawerContent">
      <StackLayout cssClass="headerContent">
        <Label text="Navigation Menu"/>
      </StackLayout>
      <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout cssClass="drawerMenuContent">
          <Label text="Primary" cssClass="drawerSectionHeader" />
          <Label text="Social" cssClass="drawerSectionItem" />
          <Label text="Promotions" cssClass="drawerSectionItem" />
          <Label text="Labels" cssClass="drawerSectionHeader" />
          <Label text="Important" cssClass="drawerSectionItem" />
          <Label text="Starred" cssClass="drawerSectionItem" />
          <Label text="Sent Mail" cssClass="drawerSectionItem" />
          <Label text="Drafts" cssClass="drawerSectionItem" />
        </StackLayout>
      </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
  </drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
</drawer:RadSideDrawer> 
</dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer>

<StackLayout cssClass="mainContent">
    <Label text="{{ exampleText }}" textWrap="true" cssClass="drawerContentText"/>
    <Button text="Toggle Drawer" tap="toggleDrawer" />
</StackLayout>
</dpg:DrawerPage>
```

And this is my `main-page.js`

```
var drawer;

exports.loaded = function(args) {
var page = args.object;
drawer = page.getViewById("drawer");
};
exports.toggleDrawer = function() {
drawer.toggleDrawerState();
};
```

The error I'm getting while tapping the **Toggle Drawer** Button (which executes the **toggleDrawer()** function) is the next:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleDrawerState' of undefined.`

Maybe you could help me guess what's going on here, because I'm pretty confused about this error right now.

**Please tell me any additional info I could provide for making this issue clearer.**

**Thanks in advance! =)**

Comment: The problem is that you try to get the RadSideDrawer instance too early. To avoid this problem you should  initialize the `drawer` on `onNavigatedTo` Page Event. You should just move this `drawer = page.getViewById("drawer");` line in  `onNavigatedTo`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! =D
I'm a bit confused here; my drawer definition is in my .js and my "onNavigatedTo" event is in my .xml.
How could I tie them up together?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this so that you will never depend on any global scope, as it will take object that you just tap on no matter what it is:

```
exports.toggleDrawer = function(args) {
    var drawer = args.object;
    drawer.toggleDrawerState();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it! My "**loaded**" directive in my **.xml** was calling `pageLoaded()` but that function doesn't exists! It is called `loaded()`.

So I have to fix the "loaded" directive:

```
<dpg:DrawerPage loaded="loaded" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo"  
xmlns:dpg="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/drawerpage"
xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer"
xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
```

To reflect the function's name

```
exports.loaded = function(args) {
var page = args.object;
drawer = page.getViewById("drawer");
};
```

---

Or I can change the function's name to reflect the directive call (pageLoaded version)

```
<dpg:DrawerPage loaded="pageLoaded" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo"  
xmlns:dpg="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/drawerpage"
xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer"
xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
```

&

```
exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
var page = args.object;
drawer = page.getViewById("drawer");
};
```

---

**Thank you all for your help! =D**